# The picture in the background of the site does not increase

Tags: html, css

I am writing a website and I have a problem. The background picture is not enlarged.
Here is a picture:
[image]

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link rel="reset.css">
</head>
<body>
  <header class="header">
    
  </header>
  <main>
    
  </main>
  <footer>
    
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.header{
  background: url(images/Group2264.svg) no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  width: 3000px;
  height: 2000px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}
```

Help me with this please!

Comment: background-size: cover should help

Answer (score 0):

The first commenter was right, but you need to use it like this:

```
    .header{
  background: url(images/Group2264.svg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

**background-size: cover;** :  "sets the size of the element's background image" - MDN.

OR

**width: 100%;** : to fill up the parent 100%, width wise. (very pseudo responsive)

**height: 100%;** : to fill up parent 100%, height wise. (very pseudo reponsive)

Comment: Some explanation would help improve this answer.